# HashMap lexicographic sort java if value is same

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I have the following `HashMap<String,Integer>` which is sorted in descending order based on Value using `Comparator`

```
Collections.sort(entryList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>() {
@Override
public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> entry1, Entry<String, Integer> entry2) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return entry2.getValue().compareTo(entry1.getValue());
}
```

> `b=3, cococ=2, 5005=1, p=1, sees=1, k=1, dad=1, pip=1, peep=1`

I now want to sort entries in this map in lexicographic order, only if values are same (for value 1 in this example)

`b=3 cococ=2 5005 = 1 dad = 1 k = 1 peep = 1  p = 1 pip=1 sees=1`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a double criteria to sort the map, first checking if the key is the same and aif so sorting by key...

```
public int compare(Entry<String, Integer> entry1, Entry<String, Integer> entry2) {
    int ret = entry2.getValue().compareTo(entry1.getValue());
    if (ret == 0) {// if 0 the are the same then compare the keys
        return entry1.getKey().compareTo(entry2.getKey());
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A concise way to do it using java 8 and comparator chaining:

```
myMap.entrySet().stream()
                .sorted(Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
                .thenComparing(Entry::getKey))
                .collect(toList());
```

**Explanation.** We are basically streaming the entries in the `Set<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>`, then sorting it first using the handy static `comparingByValue()` method on the `Entry` interface and then reversing with the `reversed()` method it to get the descending order. Then chaining another comparator that will do the second level sorting by using the `thenComparing()` method, a default method on the Comparator interface that returns a lexicographic-order comparator and takes a function to extract the sort key. We provide the exact method reference to `Entry::getKey` as a parameter.

> **Type inference.** We had to add the extra type information to the `comparingByValue()` method in the compound expression so that
>   the target type of the `thenComparing()` method can be inferred. If
>   you don't provide extra type info somewhere the compiler won't be able
>   to get the type based on type inference and you will get compiler errors.

**Your example.** The code in your example now looks like this:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap(){{ put("dad", 1); put("pip", 1); put("peep", 1); put("b", 3); put("cococ", 2); put("sees", 1); }};

List<Entry> sortedEntries = myMap.entrySet().stream()
                                     .sorted(Entry.<String, Integer>comparingByValue().reversed()
                                                  .thenComparing(Entry::getKey))
                                     .collect(toList());

System.out.print(sortedEntries);
```

So starting with *input*

> {b=3, peep=1, sees=1, dad=1, pip=1, cococ=2}

It will return the *output*

> [b=3, cococ=2, dad=1, peep=1, pip=1, sees=1]